# 2sxc - error when deleting Custom Content View

Tags: 2sxc

When I try to delete Custom Content View I get message:
[LINK](http://shrani.si/f/43/xl/4RKZ6qxL/error1.png)

I trying to delete this view to cleanup what I tested,
but don't know how to force delete this or how to find
parent 2200 (2SexyContent-ContentGroup) and parent 2206 (2SexyContent-ContentGroup) that I can delete it and then delete view.

I already deleted everithing that I think that can be part of this object, but like error show, I can't do this.

```
DNN 9.1.1.
2sxc 9.5.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

force delete has not been implemented yet, but you can easily do it by changing the scope to "2SexyContent-System" and there delete the correct template entity.

check out http://2sxc.org/en/blog/post/advanced-dynamic-data-content-understanding-content-type-scopes to change scopes.